# Why don't static methods and static nested classes have direct access to instance variables?

Tags: java

By direct access, I mean why can't they access instance variables without the use of an instance of the class the fields belong to?
If possible, please answer in terms of memory.

Comment: Because there aren't any. Not a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non static field is in each an instance, nowhere else.

In a static method, you don't have a default reference to an instance, so there is no way for the method to know which instance you have in mind.

The problem is not a matter of addresses or memory, it's a logic problem.

It's like saying, "I am not lost, I just don't know where I am. Please explain this using a Map."

Comment: So non-static methods have default references to instances?

Comment: @KacyRaye The outer class has a reference to `this` which is optional in many cases.  Nested classes can have references to their outer classes as well. At the JVM level, `this` is passed as the first parameter for you.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple. Without an instance, there is nothing to access.

Or, in terms of memory: What you are trying to access, doesn't exist in memory.

**EDIT**

If, as @Alnitak suggests below, there is an instance somewhere, this doesn't help at all. You need a reference to the specific instance for the JVM to be able to find it's members.

Comment: that's clearly not correct.  If an instance exists, it's in memory.  However the compiler will refuse to allow you to write code to try and access it, because Java does not provide raw memory access.

Comment: _without the use of an instance of the class the fields belong to_ to me implies that there is no instance.

Comment: I read that as "_no instance supplied_", not "_no instance exists_"

Answer (score 3):

Take this program for example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = Math.random();
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

It is clear that you can call [Math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) without ever having created an instance of class Math; random() is a static method, that means it is not bound to an instance of the class, it can be used without one. Consequently it cannot access the variables of an instance of Math, because which instance should it use? There could be hundreds or none at all.

The same goes for static inner classes, they are not bound to an instance of the outer class and can be created and used independently.

Answer (score 0):

It is also to keep namespacing clear. Even if they are static, you will still have compiling errors if the program attempted to access the method/class.